# Convert CURL to C# PushBullet Api

Tags: c#, curl

Guys i don't know how to covert curl to c# code.

I need to convert this

```
curl -u <your_access_token_here>: https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me
```

And try like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer <your_access_token_here>";
        //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        string text;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

But nothing.. please help me with this! Thx guys!

Api i need to use: https://docs.pushbullet.com/http/

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: As the question is worded currently, it's a bit too broad.  Without a description of what's happening/what's expected to happen, debugging it isn't very easy...

Comment: GET request implies query string parameters so start there.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I didn't even notice that, but you're probably on the right track...either the token has to be passed in as a query string, or (more likely) the method needs to be changed to POST...

Comment: @user2366842, when i change a GET to POST, i have error 401

Answer (score 0):

```
                //Подумал, и решил переделать через webclient
                WebClient^ Клиент = gcnew WebClient();
                Клиент->Headers->Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
                String^ Ответ_Сервера = Клиент->DownloadString("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me");

                JObject^ Json_Объект = JObject::Parse(Ответ_Сервера);
                String^ Идентификатор_Пользователя = Json_Объект["iden"]->ToString();
```

Comment: Please make english examples as this is an english site

Answer (score -1):

```
         //C++ code, but convert it so easy
         HttpWebRequest^ request = (HttpWebRequest^)WebRequest::Create("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me");
         request->Method = "GET";
         request->Accept = "application/json";
         request->Headers->Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
         request->UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
         request->ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
         request->ContentLength = 0;

         auto response = request->GetResponse();

         auto dataStream = response->GetResponseStream();
         StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(dataStream);
         String^ responseFromServer = reader->ReadToEnd();
         MessageBox::Show(responseFromServer);
```